# How to set operationTimeout in Couchbase NodeJS SDK 3X?

Tags: node.js, timeout, couchbase, couchbase-nodejs-sdk

I used CouchBase **NodeJS SDK 2.6.10** previously and setting **operationTimeout** was something like this:

```
const couchbase = require('couchbase')

var cluster = new couchbase.Cluster('couchbase://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX');

cluster.authenticate('USERNAME', 'PASSWORD')

var bucket = cluster.openBucket('statistics')

**bucket.operationTimeout = 3600000**
```

But, now in **SDK 3.0.4**, it's a bit different, like:

```
const couchbase = require('couchbase')

const cluster = new couchbase.Cluster('couchbase://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX', {

    username: 'USERNAME',

    password: 'PASSWORD'

})

const bucket = cluster.bucket('statistics')

const collection = bucket.defaultCollection()
```

Here, I'm not finding any option to set **operationTimeout** from. Does anybody know anything about it?

Comment: This question was also posted to the Couchbase forums, and there is some discussion there: https://forums.couchbase.com/t/how-to-set-operationtimeout-in-couchbase-nodejs-sdk-3x/26527/2

Comment: Yes Sir, I posted there. The same question I have also posted in Yahho answers: https://in.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20200623063905AAHBol1

Answer (score 0):

I can see they have timeout options for their latest nodejs sdk 3.1 but not for v3.0

api ref: https://docs.couchbase.com/sdk-api/couchbase-node-client/Cluster.html

Posting from the thread mentioned by  Matthew.

For v3.1,

```
const couchbase = require(‘couchbase’);

await couchbase.connect(‘couchbase://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX’, {
 username: 'USERNAME',
 password: 'PASSWORD',
 kvTimeout: 3600000,
 kvDurableTimeout: 3600000,
 viewTimeout: 3600000,
 queryTimeout: 3600000,
 analyticsTimeout: 3600000,
 searchTimeout: 3600000,
 managementTimeout: 3600000
});
```